# Remove line from file in bash script using sed command

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to remove lines from a text file from a Bash Script using command sed.

Here is how this function works.
User enters record number
Program Searches for record number 
Program deletes record

Here is my code:

```
r=$(grep -h "$record"  student_records.txt|cut -d"," -f1)  #find the record that needs to be deleted
echo $line -->> This proves that previous command works
sed -i '/^$r/d' student_records.txt  -->> this does not work
```

Any ideas?

Comment: They are unique records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a line containing `$record` from the file:

```
grep -v "$record" student_records.txt >delete.me && mv -f delete.me student_records.txt
```

In the above, `$record` is treated as a regular expression.  This means, for example, that a period is a wildcard.  If that is unwanted, add the `-F` option to `grep` to specify that `$record` is to be treated as a fixed string.

#### Comments

Consider these two line:

```
r=$(grep -h "$record"  student_records.txt|cut -d"," -f1)  #find the record that needs to be deleted
echo $line -->> This proves that previous command works
```

The first line defines a shell variable `r`.  The second line prints the shell variable `line`, a variable which was unaffected by the previous command.  Consequently, the second line is not a successful test on the first.

```
sed -i '/^$r/d' student_records.txt  -->> this does not work
```

Obseve that the expression `$r` appears inside single-quotes.  The shell does not alter any inside single quotes.  Consequently, `$r` will remain a dollar sign followed by an `r`.  Since a dollar sign matches the end of a line, this expression will match nothing.  The following would work better:

```
sed -i "/^$r/d" student_records.txt
```

Unlike the `grep` command, however, the above `sed` command is potentially dangerous.  It would be easy to construct a value of `r` that would cause `sed` to do surprising things.  So, don't use this approach unless you trust the process by which you obtained `r`.

#### What if more than one line matches `record`?

If there is more than one line that matches `record`, then the following would generate an `unterminated address regex` error from `sed`:

```
r=$(grep -h "$record"  student_records.txt|cut -d"," -f1)
sed -i "/^$r/d" student_records.txt
```

This error is an example of the surprising results that can happen when a shell variable is expanded into a `sed` command.

By contrast, this approach would remove all matching lines:

```
grep -v "$record" student_records.txt >delete.me && mv -f delete.me student_records.txt
```

Comment: Thanks John for the clarification!

Comment: You should perhaps also point out the obvious `sed -i "/^$record,/d" student_records.txt`

Comment: @tripleee Good point.  I added that command along with a discussion of the security issues associated with it.

Comment: Using `grep` to obtain `$r` from `$record` is rather roundabout, still.

Comment: @tripleee Very true.  My proposed solution was just to look for `$record` and delete that line via `grep`.  This makes unnecessary the creation of `r`.  (The same direct approach could be done with `sed -i`.)